# Angular2 and electron route issue

Tags: angular, electron

i have a problem understanding how angular and electron work together talking about routing.
After creating the main window with electron what i want to do is, using a route, opening a new window with that route but returns error as the following:

```
    http://localhost:4200/test/inline.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/polyfills.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/scripts.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/styles.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/vendor.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/main.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/inline.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/polyfills.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/scripts.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/styles.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/vendor.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/test/main.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Electron main.js file is:

```
'use strict';
const electron = require('electron');
// Module to control application life.
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = electron;

let win;
let winAttendant;

ipcMain.on('supportRequest', (e, type, threadObjectId) => {
    // console.log(args[0]);
    // e.sender.send('channel1', 'ok got it');
    // console.log('1:' + e + '2:' + type + '3:'+ threadObjectId)
    if (type == 1) {
        attendantWindow(1, threadObjectId);
    } else if (type == 2) {
        attendantWindow(2, threadObjectId);
    } else {
        attendantWindow(0);
    }

})

function attendantWindow(type, threadObjectId) {
    if (type == 1) {
        winAttendant = new BrowserWindow({
            x: 500,
            y: 500,
            minWidth: 300,
            minHeight: 650
        });

        winAttendant.loadURL('http://localhost:4200/attendantpage/'+ threadObjectId);

        winAttendant.on('closed', () => {
            // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
            // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
            // when you should delete the corresponding element.
            win = null;
        });
    } else if (type == 2) {
        console.log('type is: 2 and id: ' + threadObjectId)
        winAttendant = new BrowserWindow({
            x: 500,
            y: 500,
            minWidth: 300,
            minHeight: 650
        });
        console.log('http://localhost:4200/test/');
        winAttendant.loadURL('http://localhost:4200/test/');

        winAttendant.on('closed', () => {
            // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
            // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
            // when you should delete the corresponding element.
            win = null;
        });
    } else {
        winAttendant.close();
    }
}

function createWindow() {

    let electronScreen = electron.screen;
    let size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;

    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        minWidth: 900,
        minHeight: 700,
        center: true
    });

    let url = 'file://' + __dirname + '/index.html';
    let Args = process.argv.slice(1);

    Args.forEach(function (val) {
        if (val === "--serve") {
            url = 'http://localhost:4200'
        }
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    win.loadURL(url);

    // Open the DevTools.
    // win.webContents.openDevTools();

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    win.on('closed', () => {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        win = null;
    });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

component to open in new window is a simple new and clean component created with ng g c test.

Can someone help me understanding the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem because of the wrong way of trying to deal with Electron and angular2.

To deal in the correct way and pass parameters between Electron and Angular2 just use Angular2 ActivatedRoute + ipcMain from electron:

In electron main.js:

```
ipcMain.on('chat', (e, args) => {
  console.log('mainjs threadId: ', args);
  threadId = args;
  createChatWindow(threadId);
});

function createChatWindow(threadId) {
  // Initialize the window to our specified dimensions
  chatWin = new BrowserWindow({width: 400, height: 500});

  // Specify entry point
  chatWin.loadURL('http://localhost:4200/attendantsupportchat;threadId='+threadId.threadId+';type='+threadId.type);
  console.log(threadId.threadId);

  // Remove window once app is closed
  chatWin.on('closed', function () {
    win = null;
  });
};
```

In Angular2 component:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

then initialize in constructor like so:

```
public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;
```

and use where needed like so:

```
this.paramsFromElectron = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
this.threadId = this.paramsFromElectron.threadId;
this.threadType = this.paramsFromElectron.type;
```

Hope could be helpful

Comment: It works for an hosted application `http://localhost:4200` but what about a local one?